# Minikube Retriable failure: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: hyperkit crashed! command line:

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Attempting to create a Kubernetes cluster using MiniKube based on these instructions:  https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/macos/ which appear relatively straightfwoard. Installing Minikube appears to go smoothly until I attempt to start it with command:

> minikube start

Running that command results to these errors:

```
  Retriable failure: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: hyperkit crashed! command line:
  hyperkit loglevel=3 console=ttyS0 console=tty0 noembed nomodeset norestore waitusb=10 systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=yes random.trust_cpu=on hw_rng_model=virtio base host=minikube
  Deleting "minikube" in hyperkit ...
  Creating hyperkit VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ..
```

System details are as follows:

- OS: mac mojave 10.14.2
- Docker: version: 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
- VirtualBox: version 6.0.14,133895

I have also enabled VirtualBox kernel properties in System Preferences.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you start your **Minikube** on **MacOS** without any flag:

```
minikube start
```

it assumes you want to use the **default hypervisor** which in this case happens to be [hyperkit](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit) and the above command is equivalent to:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit
```

It looks like [hyperkit](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit) is not properly configured on your system and that's why you get the error message.

In order to tell your **Minikube** to use **VirtualBox** you need to specify it in its `start command`:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
```

If you don't want to provide this flag each time you start your **Minikube** you can set [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) as the **default driver** by issuing the following command:

```
minikube config set vm-driver virtualbox
```

After that each time you run:

```
minikube start
```

it will use **VirtualBox** as the virtualization technology to run your **Minikube** instance.